# Storing multiple image files in a dictionary

Tags: python, image, dictionary, random, pygame

I'm relatively inexperienced in python and was writing a shooter game for a school project. I'm trying to de-duplicate some variables which hold images:

```
wavetransition=pygame.image.load("TransitionScreen.png")
wavetransition=pygame.transform.scale(wavetransition,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
wavetransition2=pygame.image.load("TransitionScreen1.png")
wavetransition2=pygame.transform.scale(wavetransition2,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
wavetransition3=pygame.image.load("TransitionScreen2.png")
wavetransition3=pygame.transform.scale(wavetransition3,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
wavetransition4=pygame.image.load("TransitionScreen3.png")
wavetransition4=pygame.transform.scale(wavetransition4,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
wavetransition5=pygame.image.load("TransitionScreen4.png")
wavetransition5=pygame.transform.scale(wavetransition5,(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
```

these images are used as transition screens between levels in the game. They are then called in a random.randrange() variable:

```
rander=random.randrange(1,4)#Just For These Numbers To Redefine
if rander2==1:#The Random Backgrounds Displayed On The Wave Screen
      screen2.blit(wavetransition,(0,0))
if rander2==2:
      screen2.blit(wavetransition2,(0,0))
if rander2==3:
      screen2.blit(wavetransition3,(0,0))
if rander2==4:
      screen2.blit(wavetransition4,(0,0))
if rander2==5:
      screen2.blit(wavetransition5,(0,0))
```

is there any way to make this appear 'shorter'? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lists and iterations:

```
# image paths
img_paths = ["TransitionScreen.png", "TransitionScreen1.png", ...]

wavetransitions = []
for img_path in img_paths:
    # loads, resizes and adds image to wavetransitions list
    img = pygame.image.load(img_path)
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    wavetransitions.append(img)

# as rander2 is the index+1 of the image, you can simply do
screen2.blit(wavetransitions[rander2 - 1], (0, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will use lists and iterations and the check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `list` for images and a `dict` for `wavetransitions`:

```
import re
import random

images = ["TransitionScreen0.png",  # Note, added 0 to the filename
          "TransitionScreen1.png",
          "TransitionScreen2.png",
          "TransitionScreen3.png",
          "TransitionScreen4.png"]

wavetransitions = dict()

for image in images:
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)$', image.split('.')[0]).group(0)
    key = "wavetransition" + m  # m is the number that ends the name of image
    value = pygame.image.load(image)
    value = pygame.transform.scale(value, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    wavetransitions[key] = value

wavetransitions_keys = wavetransitions.keys()

screen2.blit(wavetransitions[random.choice(wavetransitions_keys)], (0, 0))
```